# Remove everything before comma from output of sorted array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is my code. The output equals "Bothell,4". What can I do to make the output "Bothell" without the comma and count portion?

```js
let As = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

let towns = new Map();

for(let a of As)
{
  let town = a.textContent.split(',')[1].trim()
  if(towns.has(town))
  {
    towns.set(town, towns.get(town)+1) 
  }
  else
  {
    towns.set(town, 1);
  }
}

let most = [...towns.entries()].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0]

console.log(most);
```

```html
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bellevue</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Kirkland</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Monroe</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
```

Comment: do you mean most[0]?

Comment: Add another `[0]` at the end?

Comment: or towns.keys() instead of entries()

Comment: Wow... it was literally just adding another[0]. Thanks so much!!

Comment: keys works as well. Thanks all!

Comment: @user120242 your answer would work if you changed it to: `[...towns.keys()].sort((a, b) => towns.get(b) - towns.get(a))`

Answer (score 1):

Just most[0] would have fixed your code.

Changed to just track maximum count.

```js
let As = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

let towns = new Map();
let max = [];

for(let a of As)
{
  let town = a.textContent.split(',')[1].trim()
  if(towns.has(town))
  {
    const count = towns.get(town)+1;
    towns.set(town, count);
    max[count] = town;
  }
  else
  {
    towns.set(town, 1);
    max[1] = town;
  }
}

let most = max.pop()

console.log(most);
```

```html
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bellevue</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Kirkland</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Monroe</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
```

Comment: @user120242 You are sorting on keys. Bothell being the first is a coincidence. I think OP needs the most frequent town in the collection.

Comment: @KevinBoroumand This is completely wrong. This is just subtracting the second letter of each word in the compareFunction like `"o" - "e"`. You need to change it to:  `towns.get(b) - towns.get(a)`

Answer (score 0):

`[...towns.entries()]` is an Array of Array(2). Just pick the first element of the first element of the sorted. You don't need the `entries`-part by the way, just spread the `Map` to an `Array`.

Alternatively you can use a reducer to create a frequency table, included that in te snippet.

```js
let towns = new Map();

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(href => {
  const town = href.textContent.split(',')[1].trim();
  if(towns.has(town)) {
    towns.set(town, towns.get(town)+1) 
  } else {
    towns.set(town, 1);
  }
});

const most = [...towns].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0][0];
//                                                    ^ here
console.log(most);

// alternative use reduce to create a frequency table
const freqs = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')]
 .reduce( (acc, val) => {
   const town = val.textContent.split(',')[1].trim();
   return {...acc, [town]: acc[town] ? acc[town] + 1 : 1 };
  }, {});
// now you need entries ;)
console.log(Object.entries(freqs).sort( (a, b) => b[1] - a[1] )[0][0]);
```

```css
a {display: block}
```

```html
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bellevue</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Kirkland</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Monroe</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
```